# combining multiple boxplots to one figure using ggplot r

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Using the following code I have created 4 boxplots:

```
bxp1<-ggplot(setTxy,aes(x=VolumCat2, y =perc_DVHT_99, fill=displ),position=position_dodge(width=5)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = My.labels)+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9"))+
      labs(title="Translation x-,y-direction",y="Ratio",ymin=0.5, ymax=1.2)
 
bxp3<-ggplot(setTz,aes(x=VolumCat2, y =perc_DVHT_99, fill=displ),position=position_dodge(width=5)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      scale_x_discrete(labels = My.labels)+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9"))+
      labs(title="Translation z-direction", x="Volume category",y="Ratio",ymin=0.5, ymax=1.2)

 bxp2<- ggplot(setTxy,aes(x=VolumCat2, y =perc_DVHR_99, fill=displ),position=position_dodge(width=5)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = My.labels)+
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9"),name="Displacement")+
        labs(title="Rotation x-,y-direction", y="Ratio",ymin=0.5, ymax=1.2)

 bxp4<- ggplot(setTz,aes(x=VolumCat2, y =perc_DVHR_99, fill=displ),position=position_dodge(width=5)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        scale_x_discrete(labels = My.labels)+
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999","#E69F00","#56B4E9"),name="Displacement")+
        labs(title="Rotation z-direction", x="Volume category",y="Ratio",ymin=0.5, ymax=1.2)
 
 figure<- ggarrange(bxp1,bxp2,bxp3,bxp4,
          labels=c("a","b","c","d"),
          ncol=2,nrow=2)
 annotate_figure(figure,
                 top=text_grob("Ratio D99",color="black",face="bold",size=12),
                 fig.lab="Figure 1" )
```

This creates the image
[image]

But how can I make the following changes:
1)for the top two boxplots I would like to loose the x labels
2)for all the plot I would like to have the same y-axis spacing
3)for the left two boxplots I would like to loose the explanation of the "boxes"called displ
If possible I would like to loose this for all plots and just add on top of the 4 boxplots that grey represent a 0.5 mm , orange a 1.0mm and bleu a 1.5mm displacement

Other suggestions to make this Figure look nicer are welcome

```
My.labels<-c("0-1cc\nn=39","1-5cc\nn=25","5-10cc\nn= 15","10-15cc\nn=6","15-20cc\nn=4",">20cc\nn=42")
```

`dput()` gives:
setTxy is a long structure looking like :

```
structure(list(displ = c("0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", 
    "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm", "0,5 mm"), 
    perc_DVHT_99 = c(0.99169574073565, 0.983998642978761, 
    0.993452539098338, 0.983301531618343, 0.978633859305831, 
    0.97572227542085, 0.993287258697977, 0.993033293087417, 0.95287598273786, 
    0.970386976259169), 
    perc_DVHR_99 = c(0.998593284244034, 0.999335925776935, 
    0.996706003069954, 1.00115102497025, 0.96614985358813, 1.01255533813509, 
    1.00579263638508, 0.989133602564636, 0.955562258557279, 0.973325763729247), 
    perc_covT = c(0.996966632962588, 0.993933265925177, 0.997977755308392, 
    0.993933265925177, 0.99388379204893, 0.988786952089704, 0.99592252803262, 
    0.99592252803262, 0.992957746478873, 0.994969818913481), 
    perc_covR = c(0.998988877654196, 0.998988877654196, 0.998988877654196, 
    1, 0.986748216106014, 1.00509683995923, 1.00203873598369, 
    0.994903160040775, 0.992957746478873, 0.995975855130785), 
    VolumCat2 = c("e", "e", "e", "e", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", 
    "b1", "b1")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
     "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the first ten rows only displ "0.5mm"is present, but the displ for "1.0 mm" and "1.5 mm" is in same format but different row numbers

setTz is has the same structure

Comment: Please `dput()` your data. This question is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve your goals here. Because you want all the y-axis "Ratio" to have the same scale and the x-axis is always the same, the simplest way is to plot using `facet_wrap()` with `ggplot`.

```
library(data.table) # to use rbindlist()
library(dplyr) # to use mutate() and the pipe operator (optional)
library(tidyr) # to use gather()
library(ggplot2)

# first, combine setTxy and setTz into a single data frame and create a single column for all your "Ratio" values and one for the panel groups
dat <- rbindlist(list("x-,y-direction" = setTxy, "z-direction" = setTz), idcol = "source") %>% 
  gather(perc, Ratio, perc_DVHR_99, perc_DVHT_99) %>% 
  mutate(
    perc = gsub("perc_DVHR_99", "Rotation", perc), 
    perc = gsub("perc_DVHT_99", "Translation", perc), 
    panel_name = factor(
      paste(perc, source), 
      levels = c("Translation x-,y-direction", "Rotation x-,y-direction", "Translation z-direction", "Rotation z-direction")
    )
  )

# create a multi-panel plot with facet_wrap()
ggplot(data=dat, aes(VolumCat2, Ratio, fill = displ)) + 
  facet_wrap(~panel_name) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete("Volume Category", labels = My.labels) + 
  scale_fill_manual("Displacement", values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + 
  theme(
    legend.position = "top", # legend is positioned at the top
    strip.background = element_blank(), # "strip" refers to the part with the panel names; here, I turned its background to blank
    strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0) # the panel titles become left-aligned
  )
```

You can further modify the aesthetics using `theme()`. Run `?theme` for more information.

P.S. - Notice in `dat`, for simplicity, I named the panel groups according to your four plot titles by renaming your variables while creating this data frame. You can, of course, [do the renaming directly in the ggplot instead](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-change-ggplot-facet-labels/).

If you want to use other multi-**plot** alternatives, you can look into [cowplot's `plot_grid()`](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) or [gridExtra's `grid.arrange()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html) options.

**Edit**

To change the arrangement of the panels created by `facet_wrap(~panel_name)`, `factor(...)` is applied in `panel_name` to assign levels, or an order, to the unique values in `panel_name`. The panel arrangement created by `facet_wrap(~panel_name)` uses the same order as the levels (in the order provided). 
Otherwise, if `panel_name` is left as `paste(...)` or a character class, the panels will be arranged alphabetically in rows.

Comment: Thanks very much, this creates the figure that I wanted. one small question: in the figure rotation is above translation, how can I change this

Comment: @Jan The `panel_name` can be changed from a character class into a factor class and using its factor levels, you can reorder them. I now updated this change into the `panel_name` code above.

Comment: Can I change Rotation x,-y-direction into 'Rotation x,y-axis?

Comment: Yes, you can rename the variable however you wish. I suggest you use the Find menu in R Studio to find all and replace all when you do it.